# PHP: Get output from StdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Here is an array of output from a class. How can I `echo` "Custom Field #1" on the screen?

```
WPGMZA\CustomFields Object ( 
    [fields] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => Custom Field #1 
            [icon] => address-book-o 
            [attributes] => {"elementary":"true"} 
            [widget_type] => dropdown 
        )
    ) 
)
```

Comment: `fields` is a private member so you can only access it from within the `CustomFields` object or (if applicable) by using an accessory

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks. I have changed the member to `public`, see my edited output.  Am I able to output that information now?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried your change? `$YourClassIntance->fields[0]->id` should be accessible now if there's no longer any private blockers.

Comment: @apokryfos, thanks so much for your help.  Your solution worked. I still get confused with output in formats like this :)  Can you please post your answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @apokryfos, actually I need to get "Elementary" and not "true" from the code above.  How can I output that to screen? So literally, I want to echo "Elementary" on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Having made fields public and therefore accessible you can access array values using `[index]` and object properties using `->key` for example `$YourClassIntance->fields[0]->id`
 should return 1

If you the keys of the JSON variable `attributes` then you could do:

```
$keys = array_keys(json_decode($YourClassIntance->fields[0]->attributes, true));
```

In this case to echo the first key you would do `echo $keys[0];`